# How to install artificial turf on a fiberglass rooftop deck?

Tags: deck, patio, turf

I want to install some artificial turf on my rooftop patio deck. I have seen this sort of installation in several other homes and it looks awesome; it also appears to be installed in place (ie, not just rolled out). Most of things I find online regarding installation explain the process for wooden decks, or lawns, but not fiberglass rooftop patios. Is it really just as easy as buying artificial turf and rolling it out? Or is there an adhesive? Is that safe to put on fiberglass? What is the process?

Comment: I think you'll need some type of adhesive. Possibly contact cement as it is used for rubber roof construction. How it handles against fiberglass I can't say but I think it would work fine.

Comment: Obviously outdoor carpet adhesives exist. Did you have a more specific question? Is your deck actually fiberglass?